# class_exists seems to keep invoking the classes constructor

Tags: php

EDIT:

I fixed my typos, and calling a class IS NOT case sensitive

i'm seeing that if I have

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

and do this

```
if (class_exists('a'))
    $class = 'a';

$a = new $class();
```

I will see

```
hellohello
```

If i comment out the `if statement` then I'm okay, it will `echo` out

```
hello
```

How can I stop the `class_exists()` from running the classes constructor?

EDIT:

this is my usage

```
foreach ($this->getNamespace() as $ns) {

                    //if (class_exists($ns . '\\' . $controller))
                        $controller = $ns . '\\' . $controller;

                    if (class_exists($ns . '\\' . $model))
                        $model = $ns . '\\' . $model;
                }

                $model = new $model($this->config);
                $controller = new $controller($this->config);
```

Comment: I'm confused because your class is called `A` not `a` and your `__construct` has an `or` on the end.

Comment: So many bugs in your sample code. Since you typed this from memory, your actual problem is probably much more complex and the bug must be somewhere else entirely.

Comment: okay 1, its a sample code, and 2, calling a class is not case sensitive

Comment: @Eli You have a terrible question to answer ratio. And do you know why that is? It is because you lack problem solving strategies. In this particular case you should take your code and reduce it until you find out what exactly causes the misbehavior. It's not that hard. Instead you come to SO with a sample code which you obviously didn't even bother to test yourself. Really, is it that hard to try on your own? Sorry for the rant :)

Comment: I come here to ask then I can't think anymore... and I figured out the problem. I didn't realize I have the same echo statement in both my model and controller contractors causing the confusion. And sorry for trying to learn by asking questions. Some of us don't have the same learning capabilities as others

Comment: @Eli, what NikiC is saying is that it will help you greatly in the long run to develop your debugging skills. Learn to use things like `var_dump()` and `debug_print_backtrace()` and maybe even debuggers integrated into IDEs (such as xdebug + PDT), and you life will be much easier.

Comment: he didn't say that, he just insulted my ability to formulate my thought processes. What you said makes more sense to me and gives me something to think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the following code:

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

if (class_exists('a'))
    $class = 'a';

$a = new $class();
```

I get:

```
hello
```

Your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: ya, i'm curious as to what it could be, i edited with my code to show how its being used

Comment: @Eli, maybe `$model` and `$controller` end up being the same string?

Comment: @Eli, add a `debug_print_backtrace()` in the constructor to see how it got there.

Comment: ya! it had the same string, I was geting confused with so many files open. Sorry, you have been the most helpful. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your sample code. This is the correct code:

```
<?php
class a // Class name is lower case
{
    public function __construct() // It's __construct not __constructor
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

$class = 'stdClass';
if (class_exists('a')) { // Missing a closing parenthesis here
    $class = 'a';
}

$a = new $class();
```

This outputs:

```
hello
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b4W0iE)

Comment: I was typing the almost same answer. Code proving it is here: http://www.tehplayground.com/#UI8tEspQG

Comment: In case class `a` didn't exist, `$class` would be undefined.